# Error message icon and Password toggle icon overlapping in Android EditText

Tags: android, validation

I have used `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` for my data entries, but when i want to show the validation error message using `etPassword.setError("Please Enter at least 1 Upper case, 1 number and 1 special character.");` in my java class, the toggle password icon and error message icon are overlapping to one another. How can i get rid of that.

[image: Password field in the login page]

Comment: When using `TextInputLayout`, you're supposed to use its `setError()` method, which shows the error in a smaller `TextView` below the `EditText`. That is, call `setError()` directly on the `TextInputLayout`. Using the `EditText`'s `setError()` method will cause that ugly icon overlap, and there's not much you can easily do about that.

Comment: <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:paddingEnd="40dp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                     />